# Adjust xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml

Can someone help me to adjust my xml layout ? I want the `kkkkkkHours` display beside the `Total Hours :`. I tried `android:paddingRight`, but it still didn't display beside the `Total Hours:`. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalHours"
            android:layout_width="334dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="180dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text=" Total Hours : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/totalHours"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totalHours"
            android:text=" kkkkkkHours : " />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:layout_width="334dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:text="add claims" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:text="submit"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: change `totalHours` and `hours` , to `wrap_content` and add top and right margin to `linearLayout `

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin height and width change to wrap_content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a `RelativeLayout`, this XML might make sense. With the layout slightly refactored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalHours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hours"
        android:text=" Total Hours : "
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/submit"
        android:text=" kkkkkkHours : "
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalHours"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="submit"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/submit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="add claims"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In linear layouts,to divide the area among the children(here textViews) you can declare weightSum in parent layout(here Linear Layout) and assign layout_weight to required percentage in children.

and layout_width attribute should be either fill_parent or match_parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   <!-- use weight sum in linear layouts to divide the layout -->

    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalHours"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="180dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        <!-- use layout_weight to give the percentage of the layout -->

        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text=" Total Hours : " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hours"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        <!-- use layout_weight to give the percentage of the layout -->

        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text=" kkkkkkHours : " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: happy to help :) if you want clear understanding of layout weights, check out this http://www.7solutions.in/2013/10/weightweight-sum-in-android.html